# What determines whether text is able to be highlighted using 3-finger tap to define on OS X?

Tags: css, google-chrome

On OS X there is a trackpad option called "Look up - Tap with three fingers". What determines whether or not the text is able to be highlighted/defined?

Edit: The preference:

[image: Trackpad - System Preferences]

For example, the descriptions for the featured projects on the [GitHub explore page](https://github.com/explore) cannot be defined. (Try to define JavaScript under jquery/jquery.)

[image: GitHub explore page]

On the other hand text in this question and the answers can be defined:

[image: This stack overflow question]

Is there a set of CSS rules that determine this behaviour? I think this may be limited to Google Chrome as both work in Safari.

Comment: This OS X function is weird. I already got some funny behavior http://i.uto.io/zIyMj or http://i.uto.io/jAwNT with chrome. And BTW, it didn't work at all on firefox nightly `30.0a1 (2014-03-13)`. And BTW2, I can triple-tap on "Javascript" on Github ( Chromium Version `32.0.1681.0 (230713)` ) http://i.uto.io/DA3ND (`OS X 10.9.2`)

Comment: Most odd, I run into the same issues. It *seems* to work reliably in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the result of [a bug with Google Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=222064), which has been marked as fixed for [OS X 10.8 and newer](https://codereview.chromium.org/166903005/).